# GithubActions failed with running iOS Test Target

Tags: swift, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am a newbie in CI/CD and trying to build my app through to GithubActions, after getting successfully build, there's an error with test target.

```
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode_12.2.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild " -target" SimpleTestingTests " -sdk" iphonesimulator " -destination" "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 12,OS=14.3" " test"

Build settings from command line:
    platform = iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 12,OS=14.3

xcodebuild: error: Unknown build action ' -target'.
Error: Process completed with exit code 65.
```

These are the logs of the Github actions.

And these are what my .yml file contains;

```
name: Feature pipeline

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    env:
      # SCHEME: "Actions"
      SCHEME: 'SimpleTesting'
      DEVICE: "iPhone 11"
      DERIVED_DATA_PATH: "DerivedData"
    runs-on: macOS-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout project
      uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Build application
      run: |
        xcodebuild SimpleTesting.xcodeproj \
            -scheme SimpleTesting\ iOS \
            -destination platform=iOS\ Simulator,OS=13.3,name=iPhone\ 11 \
            clean test | xcpretty

  unit_test:
    name: Unit test
    env:
      DEVICE: "iPhone 11"
      DERIVED_DATA_PATH: "DerivedData"
      UNIT_TEST_TARGET: "SimpleTestingTests"
    runs-on: macOS-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
    - name: Run unit tests
      run: xcodebuild \
          -target SimpleTestingTests \
          -sdk iphonesimulator \
          -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 12,OS=14.3' \
          test
```

Then I think maybe the problem is the `-target` and tried it with `-scheme` but it did not work with exactly the same error.

I took the `yml` file from a Gist you can see that there are unnecessary variables in the file but I would like to learn how can I successfully run my codes? Where's the error and how can I fix this for running a successfull deployment environment file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's missing telling that the command will be in multiple lines (using `|` at the beginning)?
The `-target` argument is not valid, but I think it should work using the `-scheme` argument.
Try using this on the `run` step for your `unit_test` task:

```
      run: |
        xcodebuild SimpleTesting.xcodeproj \
            -scheme SimpleTesting \
            -sdk iphonesimulator \
            -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 12,OS=14.3' \
            test
```

Comment: when I run `xcodebuild test -scheme SimpleTesting -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 11,OS=14.3"` this worked for my terminal but on Github's machines I guess the path is not correct like `The directory /Users/runner/work/SimpleTesting/SimpleTesting does not contain an Xcode project`

Comment: Where you able to find out about the error you commented above? I'm getting the same @eemrah